# How to have Google spreadsheet add new data rows automatically after new Google Analytics report is run?

Tags: google-analytics, google-sheets

I'm using the Google Analytics add-on on Google Spreadsheets to automate weekly report recording on spreadsheets. I'd like to be able to record variables history from site launch to current date.

I have scheduled my report to be run every Monday and retrieve the variable values for the past week. The values are written on a row in the report sheet.

I want this row to be appended to another sheet where all previous rows have been recorded.

How can I do this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the code below in the script editor. Run onOpen and it will create a menu. You can run the function from the menu. It will copy your Report row to a sheet named History and then delete the copied Report row. Let me know if you have any problems.

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Weekly Report', [ 
      { name: 'Move to History', functionName: 'moveRow' }, 
      ]);   
}


function moveRow() {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Report
  // target sheet of move to named History. Change the name to what you want.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Report");
  var row = s.getLastRow();
  var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
  var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
  s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
  s.deleteRow(row);//delete just moved data from report. You may not want to do this.
  }
```